# How may versions does HBase MapReduce reads when MapReduce is run on a table ?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

suppose you have an HBase table that support versioning when a map reduce is run over this table how many version are read in Map phase, by default and how to change this behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Default versions gets created when you hit **`create 'test', 'cf'`** is 3
>
> But when you scan in hbase shell
>
> **`scan 'test'`** =>returns only latest versions.
>
> **`scan 'test', {VERSIONS => 3}`** =>returns 3 versions if it's available.
>
> In Java default scan always return latest but you can force to get
>   previous
>   versions by having this line

```
scan.setMaxVersions(int maxVersions);
```